# How do I convert lists and arrays into same dimension?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am currently trying to plot a graph, I had to find a way to map x values to the correct place, and my file only contains 1 column, which is the y values.

I know that the interpolate fuction creates an array for the x values, so I think I need to make my list of y values into an array as well, but maybe theres a different way that you guys know of.

My current attempts keep giving me the "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension" error, so I must be doing something wrong.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x1=[]
y1=[]

#xvalues run from .5 to 35, I have 2048 data points
m=interp1d([1,2048], [.5,35])
for i in range(1,2048):
    x1.append(m(i))
x=np.asarray(x1)

with open('FFT','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')
    for row in plots:
        y1.append(float(row[0]))
y=np.asarray(y1)

plt.plot(x,y,label='Loaded from file')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Title\nSubtitle')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

If anybody has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it, thanks

Comment: Can you show us what's in the CSV? check y[0] and x[0], len(x), len(y) and show us what you get. Also upload your CSV somewhere and link to it so we can reproduce.

Comment: Or better print `x.shape`, `y.shape`, `x.dtype`, `y.dtype`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,2048):
    x1.append(m(i))
x=np.asarray(x1)
```

Due to the way Python generates numbers from the `range` function that should read,

```
for i in range(1,2049):
    x1.append(m(i))
x=np.asarray(x1)
```

Otherwise it will miss out the last element in `m()`